# Darboux sums. find an integral .

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

If $$ f(x)=\cos^{17}{x}$$
I need to prove that
$$\int\limits_0^\pi{\cos^{17}{x}}=0$$ 
with Darboux sums.

Thanks

Comment: The integral of 0 is 0, so since $\pi 0 f(x)$ equals zero, the integral is zero. Though I might be misinterpreting your question...

Comment: I am sorry this is ^ 17

Comment: @user2999009: Notice that $f({\pi\over 2}+a)=-f({\pi\over 2}-a)$ i.e. it is antisymetric with respect to ${\pi\over 2}$

Comment: Self-duplicate. Nice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_0^\pi\cos^{17}{x}\ dx=\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}{\cos^{17}\big(x+\frac\pi2\big)\ }dx=\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}-\sin^{17} x\ dx=0$$
Because $\sin^{17} x$ is an odd function, each upper Darboux sum on $[0,\frac\pi2]$ has a correspondent lower darboux sum on $[-\frac\pi2,0]$ with opposite sign.

So Darboux integrals have opposite signs on $[\frac\pi2,0]$ and $[0,\frac\pi2]$ if they exist. So the integral is $0$ assuming you know bounded continuous functions are darboux integrable.

Comment: (and $17$ is an odd number)

Comment: why cos^17x=cos^17(x+pi/2)?

Comment: @user2999009: Note the ranges of integrals. If $x$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$, then $\cos^{17}x$ is same as $\cos^{17}(x+\frac\pi2)$ when $x$ goes from $-\frac\pi2$ to $\frac\pi2$. This is because $[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]+\frac\pi2=[0,\pi]$.